# ImportError: No module named 'pandas.core.internals.managers'; 'pandas.core.internals' is not a package

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

When I tried to read a pickle file that saved by a former version of pandas, it yielded an `ImportError`.

> ImportError: No module named 'pandas.core.internals.managers';
>   'pandas.core.internals' is not a package

There was no hit on stackoverflow so i would like to share my solution for this particular problem.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This error comes off due to encoding of formerly saved pickle file. If you updated pandas to newly amended version, it produces this import error.

Comment: Update pandas by running `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pandas`.

Comment: Does this seriously mean there is no way to open pickle files generated with pandas 0.23 in pandas 0.24 nor is there a way to convert between the two formats?

Comment: @LorenzWalthert Actually, there is a back door. It sounds dummy but it really works. Open your `pickle` file with `pandas 0.23` and save it another format, say `json`. Then, open `json` file with `pandas 0.24` and save `pickle` formatted file.

Comment: @Fatih1923 thanks. Yes, that what I thought must be the strategy of last resort -.-

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded Pandas: `pip install --upgrade pandas` .. and the problem was solved.

Comment: For me, I'm using the same environment (so versions of both python and pandas are the same), but I'm still getting this error..

Answer (score 28):

I was facing the same error when I was using pandas version `0.23.4`.

I have installed pandas `0.24.1` version explicitly by:

```
pip3 install pandas==0.24.1
```

This solved my problem(Python version I was using was 3.5)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, but for me, it seemed to come from the pickle package / interaction with the pandas package.

I had Pandas version 0.23.4.
I saved some pickle files with `pandas.Dataframe.to_pickle`, with python 3.6.6 & Pandas version 0.23.4.
Then I upgraded to python 3.7.2 (Pandas version 0.23.4), and was enabled to read thoses pickle files with `pandas.Dataframe.read_pickle`.
Next, I upgraded pandas to pandas 0.24.1, and it worked for me. I can read those files again.

Comment: Many thanks, indeed, upgrading from `0.23` to `0.24` does the fix!

Comment: If you have this problem in a Jupyter Notebook, like me: you might need to restart your notebook to get the new install of pandas working.

Answer (score 7):

Updating pandas would be the best solution for most cases. However if you have limitations updating your pandas version, and you need to consume pandas objects produced and pickled in a higher version, you can add class location map as below.

```
from pandas.compat.pickle_compat import _class_locations_map

_class_locations_map.update({
    ('pandas.core.internals.managers', 'BlockManager'): ('pandas.core.internals', 'BlockManager')
})
```

Comment: Worked for me when someone created a pickle from pandas 0.25 and I'm locked in with 0.20.3

Answer (score 2):

`conda update pandas`

If you use conda package manager.